# Describing a product in an ad

Tags: word-usage, passive-voice

We are preparing an ad for pictures, and we would like to write that we have certificates of authenticity for the pictures. What would be the best way to write it?

My suggestion is to use passive (but feel free to suggest your own way), but I'm not sure about the 'to be' verb:

The pictures **are** issued with an international certificate of authenticity. 
The pictures **were** issued with an international certificate of authenticity. 
The pictures **have been** issued with an international certificate of authenticity.

Also, should I prefer 'certificate of authenticity' or 'authenticity certificate' in the given sentence?

Thank you :)

Comment: You should strongly consider writing "**an** international"

Comment: Also I suggested an edit to the title that I think is more descriptive of the actual question, feel free to roll it back if you like

Comment: Each has a different meaning and purpose. Do not decide in isolation from context. Please visit [ell.se].

Comment: Do you mean you are preparing "pictures for an ad"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with **are** because each new order includes the certificate, not just orders in the past.

And go with "certificate of authenticity." 
Somehow the other one sounds weird. It's correct, but not idiomatic and doesn't roll off the tongue well.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use 'The pictures are attached with an international certificate of authenticity.'?

Comment: @ViliamJobko no. That would suggest the pictures themselves are attached to something.

Comment: Thank you. One more question: Can I use 'internationally accepted' instead of 'international' in the given sentence?

Comment: @ViliamJobko grammatically, sure. It changes the meaning, but it's not a bad change. Consider also "internationally recognized"

Answer (score -1):

> *Each picture is shipped with an international certificate of authenticity.*

or

> *Each picture is sent with an International Certificate of Authenticity.*

Comment: -1  That makes the question a "writing advice" or "rephrasing" -- OT.