# What does it mean that the word is not idiomatic to describe something?

Tags: meaning

What does the word "idiomatic" mean in a phrase like this one:

> The word "upsurge" is not idiomatic to describe a student's vast
>   improvement.

Here I am confused by the meanings of the word "idiomatic"

Webster [gives two definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiomatic):

> 1:  of, relating to, or conforming to idiom
>
> 2:  peculiar to a particular group, individual, or style

The first meaning is something that I am more familiar with - it is about some "inner meaning behind the first meanings of words". Like, for example, "That's where the rubber hits the road" is not about the actual rubber and actual road, but rather about the real reason of the problem. So, if I follow the first meaning, than the meaning in the sample sentence would probably mean that the word "upsurge" doesn't have any other possible hidden meanings and, therefore, it's okay to be used in this case (in case of describing a student's improvement).

However, if I follow the second meaning, that would mean that the word "upsurge" is not good for this particular style or situation. And that would be a direct opposite of the first interpretation.

So, which one of these two interpretations is correct?

........................................

Edit: This is an 'Is A or B right?' question, where the answer is C.

[RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiomatic) gives the appropriate sense:

> 3:  [1b] conforming to the usual manner of expression in a language [ie sounding natural to and often used by proficient native speakers]

Comment: You should have followed the link on _idiom_ (the syntactical, grammatical, or structural form peculiar to a language) in the first definition.

Comment: @Which link is that? Where is it? Do you mean the Webster link on the word "idiom" (this one: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiom)?

Comment: @Cascabel - Ah! I just realized which link that is. So, which meaning is correct? The first one or the second one? Does that mean that the word "upsurge" can be used in that case because it's not an idiom and, therefore, will not cause any other meanings that were not implied?

Comment: On the contrary: it should not be used because it does not sound natural to a native speaker. _Upsurge_ is "an upward surge in the strength or quantity of something; an increase." Could you apply quantity to "improvement"? Not really.

Comment: @Cascabel - I see. But what if it's not "improvement", but "learning" or "progress"? It looks to me that an upward surge in strength is quite possible to happen in learning or in progress. Not? (Please, take a look at where I stumbled upon this problem. It's my comments thread with a user named as **Mari-Lou A** here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388888/a-word-to-describe-an-unexpected-advancement-in-someones-learning-progress)

Comment: This is where [ngrams comes in handy](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=upsurge+of+crime%2Cupsurge+of+learning%2Cupsurge+of+progress&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1770&year_end=1993&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cupsurge%20of%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupsurge%20of%20learning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupsurge%20of%20progress%3B%2Cc0), to see frequency of usage. Good night.

Comment: @Cascabel - And that's where I am still left in confusion. While the ngram shows that the usage of "upsurge of crime" is bigger now than the usage of "upsurge of learning" and "upsurge of progress", it still shows that at least "upsurge of learning" is still correct. In fact, it shows that the usage of "upsurge of crime" is dropping and now is at the same level with the usage of "upsurge of learning" back in 70's. Besides, it also shows that in 1940 the usage of "upsurge of progress"  was way higher than the usage of both  "upsurge of learning" and "upsurge of crime" at that time.

Comment: @brilliant I think the thing Mari-Lou A was saying was that *upsurge* would be a very unusual word to find in a school report. In that respect it was not idiomatic. (An *idiom* is nothing more nor less than an accepted form of language in which people normally speak or write.)

Comment: @WS2 - I see. So, in this case the word "idiomatic" can be replaced with the word "suitable", right?

Comment: @brilliant I think you can take it that "idiomatic in the context" is a near, though not precise, synonym of "suitable".

Comment: @WS2 - I see. Thank you. Please, make it as an answer (instead of a comment) and I will mark it as best. Just one more small refining question: which of the two meanings from the Webster that I quoted in my question was Mari-Lou A using in her phrase?

Comment: @brilliant I have duly supplied an answer, but as for what Mari-Lou A may have meant, or which meaning she was referring to, I think is something best answered by her.

Comment: The primary sense of **idiom** is as both [AHD and Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiom) indicate <<  AHD n 1 ' A speech form or an expression of a given language that is peculiar to itself grammatically or cannot be understood from the individual meanings of its elements, as in _keep tabs on_.'>>  But note that they invert the order in which they rank senses for **idiomatic** : << Collins n '1. characteristic of a particular language; conforming to the usual manner of expression in a language.' >>

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - So what's your main point here? What's the main point in pointing out that inversion?

Comment: That the principal (and thus default) sense of 'idiomatic' does not correspond to that of 'idiom'. It has been pointed out before quite a few times on ELU that 'idiomatic' should be read as (as @Dan Bron says) 'representative of the usual way of [expressing / saying] things' unless the term is otherwise defined. Neither of Webster's definitions is good here. Try [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiomatic) 1[b]: 'conforming to the usual manner of expression in a language.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I see. Thank you. As the matter of fact, this was the whole reason for my confusion and, hence, asking this question. In my language "idiomatic" means plainly "being an idiom", and an "idiom" means a special combination of words, often a funny one, the meaning of which can't be derived simply from the senses of its components. Thus, as a non-native speaker of English I was quite confused here. Do you still have a link to ELU where this matter was covered? Where exactly did Dan Bron say that?

Comment: Dan Bron's comment comes after WS2's answer below. I've given a near-identical comment to the one I give above on at least one occasion, but comments don't show up in searches. Have a look at ssdecontrol's answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230419/describing-a-product-in-an-ad/230420#230420) for the default usage of 'idiomatic' (and 'certificate of authenticity' clearly isn't an idiom, though it is idiomatic).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - How could I have missed his comment! Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Upsurge*** would be a very unusual word to use in a school report. It could be said that in that context it would not be ***idiomatic***.

An ***idiom*** is nothing more nor less than an accepted form of language which people normally use.

***Idiomatic within context*** is a near, though not precise synonym of ***suitable***.

Comment: Not so much *suitable* but *representative of the usual way of doing things*.

Comment: @DanBron That is why I described it as a "near but not precise synonym". The idea of *suitable* as the same thing as *idiomatic within context* was not my suggestion, but that of the OP.